# How to make GtkLabel scrollable within GtkScrolledWindow

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk

I'm developing a Gtk GUI within R using RGtk2. Part of the GUI is a display of a protein sequence (of variable length). The protein sequence is placed in a GtkLabel with linewrapping turned on and the linewrap mode set to PANGO_WRAP_CHAR. The GtkLabel is in turn placed in a GtkScrolledWindow. Unfortunately this doesn't work as it seems the GtkLabel cannot request the right dimensions. So the question is: Is there anyway to make a scrollable GtkLabel or is there another widget I should use?

Code example:

```
window <- gtkWindow(show=FALSE)
scroll <- gtkScrolledWindow()
window$add(scroll)
label <- gtkLabel()
label$setLineWrap(TRUE)
label$setLineWrapMode('PANGO_WRAP_CHAR')
scroll$add(label)

label$setText('THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ')
window$show()
```

note that the window might have to be resized for the problem to show...

Best Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `GtkLabel` isn't inherently a "scrollable" widget, you need to add it to the `GtkScrolledWindow` with a viewport. The function `gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport` is used in C to do this, but I don't know what the equivalent in R would be. `scroll$addWithViewport(label)`?

[gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport documentation](http://people.gnome.org/~shaunm/girdoc/C/Gtk.ScrolledWindow.add_with_viewport.html)

Comment: Thanks - that solves the problem of making it scrollable, but it still doesn't request the right size. As the length of the sequence changes dynamically I would rather not have to hard-code it.